# How to save the permissions after assigning them to a user in django 1.3

Tags: django, django-guardian

I have a set of permissions, from which I am assigning some specific permissions to the user. i am using this:

```
assign('view_userreports', <objectofuser>, <objectofreport>)
```

The permission is assigned successfully, but when I goto admin interface to see the assigned permissions it dosen't highlight any of the permissions. Please help me how can I save the assigned permissions?

Comment: What is `assign` supposed to be?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Its Django-guardian function to assign the objects of the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the shortcut method should be `assign_perm` and not `assign`. See the django-guardian docs [here](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/guardian.shortcuts.html#assign-perm).

Also, note that object-level permissions will not show up on the admin Auth view (`http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/`) for the user. In your app's `admin.py` (or wherever you register your models to the admin interface), do the following:

```
from myapp.models import SomeModel
from django.contrib import admin
from guardian.admin import GuardedModelAdmin


class SomeModelAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(SomeModel, SomeModelAdmin)
```

Once you have granted a user some object-level permissions for a specific object, browse to that object in the Admin interface. Now you should have an `Object Permissions` link in the upper right of the page:

[image: Object Permissions in the Admin Interface]

Click on that and you will be able to see and manage the object-level permissions for that object for any Django user.